# Resharper and TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, resharper, visualsvn, ankhsvn

Is there any good way to deal with the class renaming refactor from Resharper when the file is under source control and TortoiseSVN is the client.  I have am trying VisualSVN right now but I haven't had the need to rename anything recently.  I don't want to change our repository just to try this out.

Also not sure if this feature alone is worth the cost of VisualSVN.

**Update:** I have uninstalled the trial of VisualSVN and tried AhknSVN.  I seems to provided the same functionality so far.

I know this my sound trivial but the indicators seem to be lacking some functionality, it seems like they don't trickle up.  (If a file in the project is different I would think the project indicator would indicate this as well.)  I tend to keep my projects rolled as much as possible, so it is hard to tell what files have changed unless the project is expanded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TortoiseSVN 1.5 has a neat hidden feature on the check in window:

Select a missing file and a new file and right-click. One of the options will be "fix move".

I tend to refactor away, and then use this to fix any files where the name has changed.

Comment: I tried this "fix move" trick with no luck.  Will it work for directories?

Comment: Not if the new directory is also new to SVN (i.e. if it hasn't a .svn or _svn subfolder). Add the new folder first (as an empty folder) and then try the move.

Comment: It appears to be "Repair Move" in TortoiseSVN 1.5.4, which I d/l'ed today, after reading this.  Thanks, this was extremely helpful.

Comment: THANKS! I have been fixing this for years by doing an Update to get the missing file, renaming my new one, Tortoise Rename the old file, delete it and rename my new file back. ugg!

Answer (score 12):

You should really check the Free as in Beer option of [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).  They made some major improvements in v2.x and I don't feel penalized anymore when doing ReSharper refactoring-ninja moves inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Looking at the demo of the new Resharper 4.5, the Resharper team uses AnkhSVN 2.0 :)

Answer (score 5):

I find VisualSVN to be well worth the money. There are ways to do it with Tortoise, but the integration of VisualSVN is very nice. I had tried over VS-integration tools before like Ankh and was not impressed. V-SVN has really upped the level of interaction with the repository from the IDE.

The quick trick in TortoiseSVN to fix the move sounds pretty nice as well, I need to try that out.

Another bonus: I've yet to "forgot" to add a file to the repository since I got Visual SVN.

Answer (score -1):

Time to branch your repository. That's the nice part about version control, you can create new branches without totaling the old ones.

Comment: huh? How is this relevant to the question?